# Poetry: How to use it locally

Tags: pip, python-poetry

I am working with a local package directory called `pkg`.

When I start a project, I usually set up a local python environment (version 3.7) and install some required packages like:

```py
# Creating virtual env
python3.7 -m venv venv/

# Activating virtual env for Linux
source venv/bin/active

# Installing required packages from local directory
pip3 install --no-index --find-links=pkg wheel
pip3 install --no-index --find-links=pkg poetry

### Usual way
pip install --no-index --find-links=pkg some_package

### new way
poetry install --find-links=pkg some_package
```

For my python project, I usually install other packages following the usual way (with `pip --find-links`) but **I would like to install local packages with poetry to handle concurrent dependencies**. Unfortunately, I can find my way into the *[poetry documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/)*.

Can you help me?

Comment: Not yet implemented. See here: https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/5983.  You can, however, specify individual wheel files. e.g in pyproject.toml: `my-package = { file = "path/to/wheel.whl" }`. Or via CLI `poetry add ../my-package/dist/my_package-0.1.0.whl`. You could also write a shellscript (and link to a bash alias) that runs that poetry command on a given dir for each file in said dir. If you're doing this enough, I would recommend you set up your own private pypi server. https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#private-repository-example